# MFP GALLERY PRODUCT VIEW ERROW POSITION

Tags: magento2.3.3

HOW I CAN CHANGE MFP GALLERY PRODUCT VIEW ERROW POSITION, i am using magento 2 ninth theme
[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            require([
            'jquery',
            'magnificPopup'
        ], function(jQuery){
            (function($) {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.product.media').magnificPopup({
                        delegate: '.imgzoom .lb',
                        type: 'image',
                        tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
                        mainClass: 'mfp-img-gallery',
                        fixedContentPos: true,
                        gallery: {
                            enabled: true,
                            navigateByImgClick: true,
                            preload: [0,1]
                        },
                        iframe: {
                            markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
                                    '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                                    '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
                                    '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
                                      '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
                                      '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'
                        },
                        image: {
                            tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
                        },
                        callbacks: {
                            elementParse: function(item) {
                                if(item.el.context.className == 'lb video-link') {
                                    item.type = 'iframe';
                                } else {
                                    item.type = 'image';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: IS there anyone can help me ?